# Pam Modules in eclipse

Tags: fedora, c, pam, c++, eclipse

I wanted to create a Pam module. I am using Eclipse as my IDE, and making the pam module in C/C++.

When I tried to include the 2 pam modules needed

```
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
#include <security/pam_macros.h>
```

and build, I get an error saying "no such file or directory", I was looking around  my system to see if I could find the pam_modules.h and pam_macros.h, but with not luck.  Maybe I was am looking in the wrong place, or I don't have them installed.

Where SHOULD they be stored, and how do I get to the point where I can use the two header files in my programs. Do I need to manually import them into Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to install the `pam-devel` package (`sudo yum install pam-devel`) which contains the header files, under `/usr/include/security`.

Then (*note the added underscore*):

```
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
#include <security/_pam_macros.h>
```